# How do I update a model using a pre-release version of Tensorflow to run in a Google Colab instance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use the [WikiReading](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/wiki-reading) dataset and model in a project and train it using a Google Colaboratory instance. For that purpose, I'm adapting the code to a Jupyter Notebook, which also uses a more recent version of Tensorflow than the provided baseline Bag of Words model did. The original paper and accompanying baseline model was published in August 2016, which predates Tensorflow 1.0.0.

I've gone some way towards the process of updating the model to Tensorflow v1.x, but I appear to have hit a roadblock. From my (fairly limited) understanding, the last step in the model is to apply a softmax function on the results. In the original model, this was done using the following function call:

```
softmax, loss = tf.contrib.learn.ops.softmax_classifier(
        joint_enc, answers, answer_embeddings, answer_biases)
```

This is then used in this statement for the optimization:

```
train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
        optimizer='Adam')
```

I can't seem to find any documentation relating to the `tf.contrib.learn.ops.softmax_classifier()` function online. I'm assuming it takes in 4 tensors in some order, most likely something like the first holds the batch to classify, the second one holds a list of the answers to predict with the 3rd and 4th holding the embedding and biases for each answer.

My problem is that I cannot find a function that maps neatly to that format with the same output and I'm not sure what transformations to apply to my tensors to get a similar result using something like `tf.nn.softmax()` without access to the documentation of `tf.contrib.learn.ops.softmax_classifier()`. How should I go about tackling this problem? Should I just rewrite the model_fcn()?

### Original model_fn()

```py
def bow_model(features, target):
    document = utils.prune_out_of_vocab_ids(features['document_sequence'], VOCAB_SIZE)
    question = utils.prune_out_of_vocab_ids(features['question_sequence'], VOCAB_SIZE)
    answers = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(target, ANSWER_NUM, 1.0, 0.0),
                         squeeze_dims=[1])
    embeddings = tf.get_variable('embeddings', [VOCAB_SIZE, EMBED_DIM])
    doc_enc = layers.safe_embedding_lookup_sparse(
        [embeddings], document, None, combiner='sum')
    question_enc = layers.safe_embedding_lookup_sparse(
        [embeddings], question, None, combiner='sum')
    joint_enc = tf.concat(1, [doc_enc, question_enc])
    answer_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
        'answer_embeddings', [ANSWER_DIM, ANSWER_NUM])
    answer_biases = tf.get_variable('answer_biases', [ANSWER_NUM])
    softmax, loss = learn.ops.softmax_classifier(
        joint_enc, answers, answer_embeddings, answer_biases)
    train_op = layers.optimize_loss(
        loss, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
        optimizer='Adam')
    return softmax, loss, train_op
```

### Partially updated model_fn():

```py
def bow_model(features, labels, mode):
    document = prune_out_of_vocab_ids(features['document_sequence'], VOCAB_SIZE)
    question = prune_out_of_vocab_ids(features['question_sequence'], VOCAB_SIZE)

    answers = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(labels, ANSWER_NUM, 1.0, 0.0))

    embeddings = tf.get_variable('embeddings',
                                 [VOCAB_SIZE, EMBED_DIM])
    answer_embeddings = tf.get_variable('answer_embeddings',
                                        [ANSWER_DIM, ANSWER_NUM])
    answer_biases = tf.get_variable('answer_biases',
                                    [ANSWER_NUM])

    doc_enc = layers.safe_embedding_lookup_sparse(
        [embeddings], document, None, combiner='sum')
    question_enc = layers.safe_embedding_lookup_sparse(
        [embeddings], question, None, combiner='sum')
    joint_enc = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[doc_enc, question_enc])

    # softmax, loss = tf.contrib.learn.ops.softmax_classifier(
    #     joint_enc, answers, answer_embeddings, answer_biases)
    # replaced by:
    logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(doc_enc, answer_embeddings, answer_biases)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=answers,
                                           logits=logits,
                                           weights=answer_embeddings)

    train_op = layers.optimize_loss(
        loss, tf.train.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
        optimizer='Adam')

    return learn.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                               predictions=softmax,
                               loss=loss,
                               train_op=train_op)
```

### Original input_fn():

```py
def get_wikireading_input():
    filename = "../train-*"
    feature_info = {k: tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64) for k in SPARSE_FEATURES}
    feature_info['answer_ids'] = tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
    def input_fn():
        features = learn.read_batch_features(
            filename, BATCH_SIZE, feature_info,
            reader=tf.TFRecordReader)
        target = features.pop('answer_ids')
        target = utils.resize_axis(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(target), 1, 1)
        return features, target
    return input_fn
```

### Updated input_fn()

```py
def input_fn():
    features = {'document_sequence': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
                'question_sequence': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
                'answer_ids': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)}

    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=filename)
    dataset = files.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
                          cycle_length=AUTOTUNE,
                          num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

    def parse_fn(serialized):
        example = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(serialized=serialized,
                                                      sequence_features=features)[1]
        labels = example.pop('answer_ids')
        labels = resize_axis(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(labels), 1, 1)
        return example, labels

    dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parse_fn, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

The full Jupyter notebook can be accessed [here](https://github.com/ThierrySt-Arnaud/wiki-reading/blob/colab-conversion/colab/wiki_reading_training_en.ipynb)

### Edit:

I have found the source for the mentioned function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/ops/losses_ops.py). The deprecation warning  says this about updating this function:

> 'Use `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` and explicit logits computation.'

Now, I'm replicating the operations of this function as follows:

```py
  logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(doc_enc, answer_embeddings, answer_biases)
  softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(answers, logits, answer_embeddings)
```

but this gives me:

> ValueError Dimensions must be equal, but are 20 and 40 for 'xw_plus_b/MatMul' (op: 'BatchMatMulV2') with input shapes: [?,?,20], [40,5000].

This makes perfect sense when I look at the constant definitions:

```py
VOCAB_SIZE = 10000
EMBED_DIM = 20
ANSWER_DIM = 2 * EMBED_DIM
ANSWER_NUM = 5000
BATCH_SIZE = 128
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
HIDDEN_SIZE = 128
```

I guess my questions now are:

- Why is ANSWER_NUM and ANSWER_DIM not equal to VOCAB_SIZE and EMBED_DIM, respectively? Shouldn't they have the same size?
- How could this have worked before?

#### Edit 2:

As I try to update and train this model, I have grown more and more confused by the way it is defined. This is largely due to my inexperience with machine learning in general and TensorFlow in particular, but there are some things that don't make sense, at least to me. I have adjusted the ANSWER_NUM and ANSWER_DIM as I mention above and updated other functions and parameters (seen in the updated model_fn above) which gives me a valid data graph but the following error when trying to fit:

> (0) Invalid argument: assertion failed: [weights can not be broadcast to values.] [weights.shape=] [answer_embeddings/read:0] [20 10000] [values.shape=] [softmax_cross_entropy_loss/xentropy/Reshape_2:0] [128 0] [is_scalar=] [0]

This probably just requires a formatting step (that I'm not entirely sure of yet) before feeding running softmax_cross_entropy(). However, I also noticed that there is no definition of the hidden layers anywhere in the original model and HIDDEN_SIZE is unused. Is there an implicit definition of those layers somewhere in the model that I'm missing?

At this point, I feel like it will be easier to just use a Keras functional model in TensorFlow 2.x to get as close as possible to the *perceived* original model.